# Managing lots of overlapping controls in one Window in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I'm working on a WPF application in which the client can select a device from a drop down list (ComboBox) and then have its specifications displayed to them in a `DataGrid` control. I have made some 20 different DataGrids for the 20 different products and I've kept them overlapping each other (on top of one another) in a predefined `Grid.Row` of my Window.xaml markup, with the Visibility of each `DataGrid` set to Hidden, such that when a `ComboBox` selection is changed I change the visibility of the DataGrid that belongs to that particular product selected from the ComboBox to `MonitorDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` in my code behind.

It does the job but managing the layout of the Window has become really arduous and a catastrophe, especially when I want to change the styles or positions of the DataGrids. I was wondering what is the best way of managing the markup of lots of controls in one window occupying the same area?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, Grid have AutoGenerateColumns property which automatically extracts columns from list given to it,

but if you have some extra properties in entity that you don't want to show, you can create templates in resourcedictionary, and keep only keys in the items of the DropDown and change grid template on itemchange

Showing and hiding grids is really the worst way to do this

Also [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) should help to do what you want

Hope this helps

Comment: hey ArsenMkrt, thanks for your help. I know the DataGrid control inside out man, I've spent days making various DataGrids with various Styles and properties. In the first part of your answer, do you mean to say that I should store the details of the products in a database, and then have just 1 DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns="True"? I would have done this initially as its the most intuitive approach, but the requirements for the applications i'm working on changed over night and initially I only had 3 devices to display now I have 20+! I guess I should do it the 'Database' way now?

Comment: @estranged, you don't need to create anything in database, you should create different classes for each grid type, and assign list of that class to ItemSource of grid,when AutoGenerateColumns property is true,single grid will populate columns automaticaly, or you can store templates in resourcedictionary and load them after drop down item selected